# Rights on linux apache to make php run a python script

Tags: php, python, linux, git, ssh

So, there has been a lot of question to this topic and I read a lot in the last few days.

Running the php script that executes the python script from command line is fine - all works (whoami customername). Running php script in browser does not work (whoami www-data).
No matter who owns both scripts, no matter what php I use to run the script (exec, system ...), php.ini checked, nothing disabled that would interfere.
If I move the php script to the very root, it seems willing to exec the python script, but fails to find SSH folder that I need to do things with python script.

I gather the problem is rights. I can run the python script from command line. I can run the php script from command line. Both do the stuff it should (SSH to git server and do some things)

Its a customer server so I am limited to the things I am able to do. Would be nice to have a button in browser to make thing happen instead of sending customer to command line.

Before I finally giving up, anyone ever had the same scenario and has found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to run shell command using php. Try this might be this helping you http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Well, thats what I said. I know the syntax, otherwise the php script wouldnt work on command line.